# Create class in Action<T> delegate

Tags: c#

I know that this code is not good and maybe it's stupid question but can anybody explain me why it works in this way?

I have this simple class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have next method with Action delegate

```
private Customer GetCustomer(Action<Customer> action)
{
    var model = new Customer { Name = "Name 1" };
    action?.Invoke(model);

    return model;
}
```

Then I execute this method with delegate and write into console model.Name

```
var model = GetCustomer(c => c = new Customer { Name = "Name 2" });
Console.WriteLine(model.Name);
```

I expected to get "Name 2". But I get "Name 1" - which is value of the class defined inside method. I understand that to get what I want - I could write code in this way:

```
var model = GetCustomer(c => c.Name = "Name 2");
Console.WriteLine(model.Name);
```

And everything will be ok. But why my first implementation doesn't work? 
I would be thankful a lot if somebody explain me this.

Comment: The method instance is not replaced, you cannot do that from within the lambda.

Comment: `c` is copy of reference to `model`. After assigning `c = new ...` `c` will refer to another isntance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c` in your lambda is only assigning to the parameter, its not assinging it back to `model` in `GetCustomer`.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expression in your case compiles into a method.
This is the same, why this code won't change `c.Name`:

```
// code below is equivalent of
// c => c = new Customer { Name = "Name 2" }
private void Foo(Customer c)
{
    // c will be changed inside method,
    // but will remain unchanged outside it
    c = new Customer { Name = "Name 2" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = GetCustomer(c => c.Name = "Name 2");
```

instead of:

```
var model = GetCustomer(c => c = new Customer { Name = "Name 2" });
```

Why? Because you want to do the changes on the same instance transferred in the new function (implements the delegate). If you create a new instance of `Customer` in new function (`c`) then it would do the changes on the new instance of `Customer` that won't be valid when `c` ends.

Same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321602/why-is-list-when-passed-without-ref-to-a-function-acting-like-passed-with-ref) but with `List`.

Comment: um he has that in the original post.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explain why this answers the question - but I think you're on the right track here for what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your lambda expression, you are just saying that `c` and `model` are pointing to the same reference.  And then you are changing the reference of `c`. At the end `model` is still referencing to the previous instance. This is the equivalent code of what you are trying to do:

```
var model = new Customer { Name = "Name 1" };
var c = model;
c = new Customer { Name = "Name 2" };
```

But, `model.Name` is still `Name1`.

You can change your code as if you want to change one of hte properties:

```
 var model = GetCustomer(c => c.Name = "Name2");
 Console.WriteLine(model.Name);
```